# How to secure webpages in ASP.Net with roles?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication

In my application I have different roles and offcourse multiple pages. How do I secure webpages that may not be accessed by certain roles?

Imagine group 1 has access to webpage a.aspx, b.aspx and c.aspx but not to webpage d.aspx. How do i secure that when a user of group 1 types in d.aspx he cannot view the page?

Comment: Do you want to implement this using .NET Role based security?

Comment: Are these roles are fixed in DB table or changeable?

Comment: For now they are fixed and stored in a table (id + description). I now have 4 roles.

Comment: We also have the same situation. Each Role have access to specific pages. What we did the same as I have posted in the answer. 1 Point to be Noted, In your case If You add 1 more role in DB, Where you put that role Accessiblity of pages????? Again you have to define that role Accessbility in web.confing.... Second option here is at runtime put these roles accessbility or produce this kind of thing runtime. I mean you have to modify web.config at runtime.....

Comment: If you define 1 more role in DB, are you adding, what are the pages can access this role? Are you storing this information? If not simply you have to hard coded in web.config.

Comment: I am not storing this information yet, but I have the choice to do it. Are there any adventages if I store this information in the database? And how does the implementation looks like?

Comment: Regarding Implementation of Security you have to add Authorization tag in web.config.... but if you store these roles in DB, obviously you will get other benefit like on user definition page where you assign role to user, you must populate these roles, if you hard code these roles you have to manupulate code.. Somewhere you need to check something from DB According to Roles, you can easly make joins with that tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add in web.config, which Role can get which page.

```
<location path="yourPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow roles="Super Admin"/>
                            <deny users="Admin"/>

        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thnx. But my roles are stored in the database. Is there a (quick neat) dynamic way?

Comment: Are these roles are fixed in DB table or changeable?

Comment: So for each page I have to create a authorization tag?

Answer (score 0):

This is a big topic but I think what you want to look into is the ASP.NET Membership Provider.

I would start here: [Examining ASP.NET 2.0's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx).

> There's one thing messageboard
>   websites, eCommerce websites, social
>   network websites, and portal websites
>   share in common: they all provide user
>   accounts. These websites, and many
>   others, allow (or require) visitors to
>   create an account in order to utilize
>   certain functionality. For example, a
>   messageboard website, like
>   ASPMessageboard.com, allows anonymous
>   and authenticated visitors to view and
>   search the posts in the various
>   forums. However, in order to be able
>   to post a new thread or reply to a
>   message a visitor must have an account
>   and must log into the site.

Comment: Thnx. I am looking for a quick and nice solution. It is not for a very big application.

Comment: What he suggest would probably be faster than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

Authorization module which applies authorization to matching urls:
http://code.google.com/p/talifun-web/wiki/RegexUrlAuthorizationModule